# How to create a menu child of an other menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

How can I create a menu child of an other menu. 
Drupal menu are links to pages or an other content type.
I want a main menu that can expand sub menus by clicking on a menu item.
So, there is a module that can create menu children of a menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module

> .. allows you to display blocks of menu links starting with any desired level of a menu and limited to any desired depth.
>
> .. you can choose to expand all menu links with children or to root
>   the menu tree to a specific menu item.